# Clients do not see DHCP Server... what am I missing?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, router, dhcp

Old router died and just got the new one in and I can't figure out what I'm missing to forward dhcp and dns to windows server 2012.

Old router was a netgear R6300, new one is an N900. Before the router died the system worked fine, now that I'm trying to set up the new one all the wired computers are saying unidentified network and there is no connection.

***The environment is setup as follows:***

- The clients are wired to a switch, which is connected to the router.
- The DHCP/DNS server is plugged directly into the router

***Troubleshooting I've done:***

- There are wireless clients also, and they can access the internet fine.
- Right now the wired clients are not receiving IP addresses.
- Bypassing the switch and connecting a client directly to the router does not solve the problem.

***I've setup the router as follows:***

- port forward 53 to server
- uncheck use router as DHCP server
- We have a static IP from our provider and I put that in.
- Under DNS Address in router I put the ones provided from our ISP (If I put the server IP here the system goes down)
- I checked the predefined options in the DHCP and I can see the router is in there correctly
- I checked the DNS and saw that I have the correct settings for the DNS servers

So what am I missing? do I need to add a static route? forward DHCP? I feel like I'm overlooking something simple, and all I did was replace a broken router, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do the old router (R6300) and the new one is an N900. have the same internal ip (192.168.1.1) for example? If this has changed and your dhcp server was a static address it may have an incorrect gateway address.

Comment: Check your network mask and broadcast port too.  Remember, DHCP is a broadcast protocol not a directed one, if you had the domain broadcast port as 0 the last time, and have it as 255 this time then chances are the clients are broadcasting on 0 and the DHCP is soliciting requests on 255 or similar

Comment: Port 53 is **DNS** (not DHCP, though many DHCP servers also do DDNS). But your post title is "Clients do not see **DHCP** server". Can you expand on what your problem is? Do the client not get an IP? Or do they get an IP and can ping eachother locally on the LAN but fail to connect to your DNS server? (thus working fine locally but probably not reaching the Internet nor resolving hostnames).